Creating a audio file using PCM data which is converted to bytes, getting audio played with a different pitch and slowed
I am using a voice call functionality in which i am extracting the audio data, the audio data i get is in PCM format which i convert into bytes array and then write it to a .wav file and then download it.
On playing that file the voice in it is actually playing like it is getting played in slow motion.
Below is the code snippet i am using to do this:
const audioData = {
track: null,
channels: []
}

this is how i am storing the PCM data:
const currentChannelData = buffer.getChannelData(channel);
console.log("PCM data in channel", channel, currentChannelData);
audioData.channels.push(Array.from(currentChannelData));
console.log(buffer.sampleRate)
sampleRate = buffer.sampleRate;

//on logging this sample rate it is, 48000

// at the end this is how i am converting final PCM data to .wav file:
function saveWavFile() {
    // Concatenate all channels
    const mergedChannels = audioData.channels.flat();
    const wavByteArray = pcmToWav(mergedChannels, sampleRate);

    // Create Blob from Uint8Array
    const wavBlob = new Blob([wavByteArray], { type: 'audio/wav' });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(wavBlob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = 'display: none';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'recording.wav';
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }

function pcmToWav(channelData, sampleRate) {
    const numFrames = channelData.length;
    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + numFrames * 2);
    const view = new DataView(arrayBuffer);

    // Write the WAV container
    writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
    view.setUint32(4, 36 + numFrames * 2, true);
    writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
    writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
    view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
    view.setUint16(20, 1, true); // PCM format
    view.setUint16(22, 1, true); // Mono (1 channel)
    view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
    view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 2, true); // Byte rate
    view.setUint16(32, 2, true); // Block align
    view.setUint16(34, 16, true); // 16-bit sample size
    writeString(view, 36, 'data');
    view.setUint32(40, numFrames * 2, true);

    // Write the PCM samples
    for (let i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
        view.setInt16(44 + i * 2, channelData[i] * 0x7FFF, true);
    }

    // Convert ArrayBuffer to Uint8Array
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    return byteArray;
  }

If someone have any idea on how to resolve this please help.
I have tried directly changing the sample rate to 16000, it make the audio to appear even more slow.
I also tried to increase sample rate, the speed of audio speech increases but the pitch of it changes very much.

So the voice data is 48kHz and you save it at 48kHz and it sounds slowed down?

yes, also the pitch of audio is changes, it sounds a little robotic, could it be a problem of wav file headers

Are you sure it's mono and not stereo ?

The thing is on setting channels equals to 2, the voice at 48000 hz is not slow but is robotic type tone and on channels equals to 1, the voice at 48000 hz is slow.
